# Javascript reference not defined, simple un-realized function

Tags: javascript

I'm puzzled on why this simple bit of code does not work. So to speak, `dash()` should be called everytime there has been a keychange. However, I'm getting a bunch of reference errors. I'm doing something wrong and I don't know what.

```
<input type="text" class="auto" onkeypress="return dash(this)" width="200px">

function dash(e) {
     alert(e);
}
```

Essentially I'm trying to grab the text from the text box, then evaluate it, then change the value of the textbox after.

http://jsfiddle.net/Q8gyY/

Comment: You have configured your fiddle in "onLoad" mode, so your `dash()` function resides in the scope of a `load` event handler, not in the global scope. Switch to "No wrap - in body" to fix your problem.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi How will this affect the code in prod? Do I need to put it in the body this way?

Comment: In production you won't hopefully use inline event handlers.